# Rails view array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

In my rails app now i have such data:

```
[[{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""},
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"},
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401D", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,42"}], 
 [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"}],   
 [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}]]
```

And view:

```
=@oem_art.each do |oem|
      -oem.each do |oo|
        %tr{:class => cycle("zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra1", "zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra2")}   
          %td
            = oo[:car]
          %td
            %h4
              = oo[:article]            
          %td
            = oo[:group]
          %td
            = oo[:price]
```

But how can i do it in more beatiful way? Also how to skip hash with empty keys?
How can i do it via standart one loop, for example:

```
=@oem_art.each do |oem|
          = oem.car
          %td
            =oem.price
```

How about flatten? But it is unusefull here...

UPD

```
  def original_art
    @article = Article.find_by_ART_ID(params[:id])
    @constr_num = ArtLookup.get_construction_number(@article.ART_ID)
    oem_art = []
    @constr_num.each do |o|
      as_oem = get_from_as_oem(o.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER)
      if as_oem.present?
        oem_art << as_oem
      end
    end    
    @oem_art = oem_art.to_a.uniq
    @article = Article.first
    @oem_art
  end
```

Comment: A `flatten` should help here? Why do you say it is not useful?

Comment: Looking at the updated code you've posted, you shouldn't need the `to_a` because `oem_art` is already an array and the `uniq` is probably not doing what you intend because it won't be removing duplicate hashes only duplicate arrays of hashes.

Comment: @mikej  didn't understand you on 100% write it in code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beauty is matter of personal taste, and `flatten` is of some use to avoid nested loops.

```
- @oem_art.flatten.reject { |h| h[:car].empty? }.each do |oem|
  = oem[:car]
  # And so on ...
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I would suggest, but it is also worth looking at the rest of the code to see if you can avoid getting the empty entries in there in the first place.

Comment: i added piece of code... there it call another method... sorry will give it only in pm

Answer (score 0):

This is the point I was making in the comment on the question. If you have `oem_art`:

```
[[{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""},
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"},
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401D", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,42"}], 
 [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"}],   
 [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
  {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}]]
```

i.e. the elements are:

```
1. [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""},
      {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"},
      {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}, 
      {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401D", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,42"}]

2. [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
      {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401A", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,564"}]

3. [{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, 
      {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"7H0127401B", :group=>"FILTER", :price=>"0,546"}]
```

If you call `oem_art.uniq` this would remove duplicate elements but the 3 elements are all different so nothing would be removed. It wouldn't actually remove the duplicates for 7H0127401A and 7H0127401B from *within* the elements.

Comment: This isn't meant to be a full answer to your question. I was just writing a longer version of the point where you said you didn't understand 100%. Cheers.